# How did Zipporah know that Moses was "strong and the trustworthy"?

Tags: tafseer, prophet-musa

In Al-Qasas 28:26 a woman advises her father to hire Musa (PBUH) to look after his flocks. She also mentions some of his qualities which make him suitable:

> One of the women said, "O my father, hire him. Indeed, the best one
> you can hire is the strong and the trustworthy."

How did she know this about Musa (PBUH)?

Answer (score 1):

Bismillahir Rahmanir Rahim. Alhamdulillahi rabbil-'alamin. Was-Salatu was-Salam 'ala Sayyidina wa Azimina, Wa Habibi Qulubina wa Shafii Nufusina, Abul Qasim Muhammad. Wa 'ala Ahli Bayti tayyibina tahireen.

---

When the daughters of Shuayb (as) returned to Shuayb (as), he (as) said to the two of them: ‘Your return was quick!’ So they related to him (as) the story of Musa (as), and he (as) did not recognise him (as). So Shuayb (as) said to one of them: ‘Go to him (as), so that he (as) can be recompensed for having watered for us’.

She went to him (as) Musa (as) stood up to go with her, and she walked in front of him (as). However, Musa (as) said to her: ‘Walk behind me (as), and show me (as) the way and I (as) shall follow the direction, for we (as) are a people who do not look
at the backs of the women’.

So when he (as) came up to Shuayb (as), related to him (as) the story. Shuayb (as) said to him (as) ‘Do not fear! You have escaped from the unjust people’. One of
the daughters of Shuayb (as) said, ‘O father! Employ him. Surely he is the best of the one you can employ, being strong, trustworthy’

Shuayb (as) said to her: ‘**As for his (as) strength, so you recognized it by his (as) drawing the bucket alone**. **How did you recognize his (as) trustworthiness?**’ She said to him (as), ‘He (as) said to me: ‘Walk behind me, and show me the way, for **we (asws) are a people who do not look at the backs of the women**’. I recognized that he (as) is from a **people who do not look at the body parts of the women, therefore this is his (as) trustworthiness**’.

[Tafseer Hub-e-Ali (page 33)](https://hubeali.com/books/English-Books/TafseerHub-e-Ali/CH28_SuraAlQasas_Verses1-42.pdf)